# how to convert hyphen to minus for exponent in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, math, data-science

Consider the following example

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib
matplotlib.rcParams['axes.unicode_minus'] = False
plt.figure(figsize = (10,7))

plt.plot(history_1.history['loss'], color = 'coral', label = 'Training loss')
plt.plot(history_1.history['val_loss'], color = 'firebrick', label = 'Testing loss')

plt.title('Training and testing loss in the function of epochs', fontsize = 18)
plt.xlabel('Epochs', fontsize = 15)
plt.yscale('log')
plt.ylabel('Loss', fontsize = 15)


plt.legend(fontsize = 15)
plt.grid()

plt.show()
plt.show()
```

The out put will be shown as follows
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rsseY.png)
Any help on how can we convert the hyphen to short dash in y axis?

Comment: Are you talking about the negative sign in the exponent?

Comment: Ftagliacarne yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a unicode hyphen like this example.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
...
plt.yscale('log')
ax = plt.gca()
old_formatter = ax.yaxis.get_major_formatter()
def new_formatter(x, pos = None):
    return old_formatter(x, pos).replace('-', '\u2010')
ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(new_formatter)
...
```